# Socket error while connecting a bridge between aws iot and local mqtt broker

Tags: mqtt, alexa-skills-kit, aws-iot

i have a mqtt broker running on my PC, to which i am trying to bridge with aws iot thing.i followed this link [HOW TO BRIDGE BETWEEN MOSQUITTO MQTT AND AWS IOT MQTT BROKER (TO PUBLISH OPENHAB SMARTHOME DATA TO THE CLOUD)](https://blog.jensihnow.de/archives/762-How-to-bridge-between-Mosquitto-MQTT-and-AWS-IoT-MQTT-Broker-to-publish-openHAB-Smarthome-data-to-the-Cloud.html)i updated the .conf file as per my iot end point and respective certificate file , private key and root CA file.but when i tried to run the mosquitto.conf file , socket error occurs.[image]

Answer (score 1):

While bridging between AWS IOT endpoint and local MQTT broker, we have to consider the below points :

- Make sure the AWS IOT endpoint is configured properly in an order, first create a "thing" , create "certificates" for the thing, download rootCA file, private key and cert.pem file to the machine where the bridge is being configured.Create a policy.
- When we create a policy select "iot:*" as Action part and "*" as Resource ARN[image: attached screenshort]
- Attach the thing and policy to certificate that was created[image: certs to be downloaded]
- make sure the certificates are downloaded to path "/etc/mosquitto/certs"
- make sure to give the topic names and QOS level that are to be bridged
- give the correct AWS IOT endpoint in the conf file
- log_type as all . so that we can verbose the logs
- create a bridge file from local mqtt broker machine, with extension as .conf, so that when we restart the mosquitto broker, this conf files gets loaded.
  consider below format for conf file:
  [image: configuration file]

Once this file is created , restart the mosquitto broker using this command:

```
sudo mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/bridge.conf –d
```

if bridge is formed properly then you can see the logs like
    connecting to bridge awsiot(with aws iot end point)
    Bridge bridgeawsiot sending CONNECT
    Received CONNACK on connection local.bridgeawsiot

1. now subscribe to the topics that we configured in the .conf file in aws iot.
2. when a client publishes to this topic via , the messages can be viewed in aws iot console

Comment: if this does not work, try changing the QOS level from 2 to 0/1.